# Parsing a Neo4J Node / Relationship to JSon

Tags: java, json, neo4j

is there any possibility to parse a node/relationship into json? Simply using GSon wouldnt do it.

Any hint would be nice :)

Best Regards,
Kai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is what you can do with the [REST API](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/rest-api-nodes.html), and there a numerous clients to that in [Neography](https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neography)[Python](http://py2neo.org/) etc...

Comment: but i dont want to use the rest api ... something like neo.toJson(Node) would be nice.

Comment: ok, then you just to object serialization, I don't think there is more to it than that ... does that work for you?